# Modifying the layout for my Content Search web part

Tags: 2013, development, web-part, css, page-layout

I have added a content search web part, and I select the following layout settings:-

[image]

The output was very poor regarding the layout:-

[image]

So can I do the following modifications:-

1. To have the items displayed inside a table (something similar to the App part’s Newsletter view template)?.
2. I tried to display more info about the items buy using a “;” as mentioned in the above picture. But seems the current layout only allow viewing two properties only?
3. From where I can change the web part colors, styles , etc? I cannot find a way using the SharePoint designer 2013?is defining a custom CSS the correct approach to follow?
4. i want to chnage the date format to be something such as 02 Aug 2014 , instead of the defualt format?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you will need to create custom Display Templates (both a control and an item template).

I would suggest the following MSDN pages:

- [What's new in SharePoint 2013 search for developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163951%28v=office.15%29.aspx)
- [SharePoint 2013 Design Manager display templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945138%28v=office.15%29.aspx)